# NSTabView vs NSTabViewController -- When to use the controller?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

The NSTabViewController was only introduced in OS X v10.10, so NSTabView already provides everything you need for creating a tab view. When would you use a NSTabViewController, and is it only there to be subclassed?

Comment: From an iOS background, but a skim of the docs confirms it.  The tab view is essential, and the view controller contains a few things typically done when one is managing a tab view.  I wouldn't subclass it (if I found myself needing a subclass I'd probably just omit it and write my own).

Answer (score 0):

If you compare iOS & OS X, you will feel OS X is bit deviated from MVC. OS X default 'new project' opens with AppDelegate as compared to iOS with 'ViewController'!

Now, it seems, Apple decided to make it by adding Controller as well. So that the view `NSTabView` is controlled by `NSTabViewController`.

And yes if you design to subclass it and use that should reduce your job. Same thing is mentioned even in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTabViewController_Class/).

Answer (score 0):

I would use NSTabViewController to get rid of a lot of code I used to have to write to have a tab view and transition between those views (most often done in Preference windows in Mac apps).

You'd obviously have to be 10.10 only, but these days that's a safe bet.

As for subclassing it, judging by the api I'd start without sub-classing it. You can set the style, the transition options (a nice benefit of using it!), and then call `addTabViewItem:` and let it do it's stuff.